# Inner product in polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

The difficulty in proving that $\left< { p }_{ 1 },{ p }_{ 2 } \right> =\sum_{i,j=0}^n \frac{a_ib_j}{i+j+1}$ is an inner product in $\mathbb {R}$ spatial vectors ${ P }_{ n }$, where $ p_{ 1 }\left( x \right) ={ a }_{ 0 }+{ a }_{ 1 }x+\cdots +{ a }_{ n }{ x }^{ n }$, $p_{ 2 }\left( x \right) ={ b }_{ 0 }+{ b }_{ 1 }x+\cdots +{ b }_{ n }{ x }^{ n }$. For me lies in proving that $\left< p_{ 1 },p_{ 2 } \right> \ge 0$. How can I prove $\left< p_{ 1 },p_{ 2 } \right> >0$. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not true. But thankfully, it doesn't have to be: all that is required of an inner product in that regard is $\langle p, p \rangle \geq 0$, which is immediate from the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\langle p_1 , p_2 \rangle = \int_0^1 p_1(t) p_2(t) dt $ and
hence if $p \neq 0$ we have $\langle p , p \rangle = \int_0^1 p^2(t) dt  >0$.